# the meaning of "had <somebody> in"

Tags: phrase-usage

[Check this.](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY3MyZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY3MyZlZD0yMDE0LTEyLTA1VDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4)

> And now, for the lover of modern and post modern art, there's the
>   Centre Georges Pompidou, which is home to France's National Modern Art
>   Museum. When first constructed, the daring and strange architecture of
>   Centre Georges Pompidou **had** Paris residents in a heated debate.

What is the meaning of "had" in the above context? What can be used instead of "had" in that context? I guess it means "led to". Am I right?

Comment: You're quite right - you could rephrase as, for example, ***...led to** Paris residents [**engaging**] in a heated debate* or ***...caused** Paris residents [**to engage**] in a heated debate*. Note that the syntax of the surrounding context may change if you alter the verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means "caused to be."  Here are some other examples:

> I had him laughing at my joke.
>   I had him completely confused with my explanation.
>   The approaching storm had me concerned.

As you can see, *in* isn't required; in your example the meaning is "caused Paris residents to be in a heated debate."  You could just as well say "had Paris residents debating heatedly," although it sounds a little stiffer.

There are similar usages.  These examples have the meaning of "caused to do":

> I had him run 20 laps around the field.
>   I had him go to the store for sugar.
>   I had him bring the beer for the party.

Then, "had him in" and "had him over" have the meaning of invited or required someone to come to a particular place:

> I had him over last weekend.  (This means that I invited him over to my house.)
>   I had him in to present his report.  (This means I invited in to the office to present his report.)
>   The police had him in for questioning.  (This isn't an invitation!)

Finally, there's a British idiom *have someone on*, which means to fool or tease someone.  Americans will say *pull someone's leg* (a little less formal than *have someone on*) or *shine someone on* in the same situation.